# SFML: unable to open .png file

Tags: png, textures, sfml

It may sound like other questions related to this matter but I don't have any problems opening rectangular .png files. Seems like my computer has problems only with non-rectangular pictures (e.g. triangular play button without the background). What can be done? I think there's no need to provide a reproducible example. Appreciate all the help.

EDIT: the error is as follows [image]

Comment: Never heard of this problem. Can you please provide the play button file somehow? And just to be sure, the relative path contains the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to put your picture in your project folder because I once made that mistake for a game that I made. You should also maybe remove Resources/res/ from the loadFromFile code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rectangle and circle shapes with textures loaded form file without problem, transparent .png's too. If you are absolutelly sure that your code is correct, you got correct file address etc.. Maybe there is a  problem with image. Try to load some another image where you 100% know that it works fine.  Maybe your antivirus is messing with your projects,. Check if you have exception for your project directories. I could be more specific if you provide some code of your attempt to us.